# Parsing(removing extra space,encoding) multiple attributes through same funtion in python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I am trying to parse data from HTML file. I will extract various information and store those in respective attributes.However before printing those results/attributes in CSV file I need to remove unwanted special characters and encode those attribute values.

```
address2='#4th avenue'
price='price is $45'


address2 = address2.encode('utf-8')
address2= re.sub('[,!@#$&]','',address2)
address2=address2.lstrip()
address2=address2.rstrip()
address2=address2.strip()


price = price.encode('utf-8')
price= re.sub('[,!@#$&]','',price)
price=price.lstrip()
price=price.rstrip()
price=price.strip()
```

Expected output:

```
price:       price is 45
address2:    4th avenue
```

I am getting the result as expected however I need to apply strip and encode for each and every attribute.
Is there a way create a function so that I can pass all the attributes in to that function . Instead of applying strip/encode to each attribute.

Something like

```
def cleanup(temp):


        temp = temp.encode('utf-8')
        temp= re.sub('[,!@#$&]','',temp)
        temp=temp.lstrip()
        temp=temp.rstrip()
        temp=temp.strip()
        return temp
```

so that I can pass the required attribute to that function

```
cleanup(address2)
cleanup(price)
```

to get the clean output

```
price:       price is 45
address2:    4th avenue
```

Since I am new to python I am not sure what is a right way of achieving this.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the return value passing the original string to the function:

```
def cleanup(temp):
   return temp.strip().translate(None,",!@#$&").encode("utf-8")

address2='#4th avenue'
price='price is $45'

address2 = cleanup(address2)
price = cleanup(price)
print address2
print price
```

Output:

```
4th avenue
price is 45
```

You don't need to use lstrip, strip and rstrip, strip will strip from both sides of the string.